# How to view wrapped content when it is out of the viewport, when the viewport is set to a specific size

Tags: html, css, web

I have been trying to center my content, and my way of doing that was setting the viewport to a certain height and centering all the content inside. However, I now want to be able to wrap my flexbox so that each image stacks on top of the other cleanly. This, however, has caused the problem that I need to scroll up to see the images because the viewport is a specific height. Are there any ways to fix this or even a better way to center all of my content, being both flexboxes and the title?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
  max-width: 50%;
  user-select: none;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #D9BCA9;
  height: 54px;
}

.top-row ul {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.top-row li {
  list-style: none;
}

.top-row li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 1rem;
  display: block;
  color: black;
}

.top-row li:hover {
  background-color: #e6c6b1;
}

.toggle-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1rem;
  right: 1rem;
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 30px;
  height: 21px
}

.toggle-button .bar {
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

@media(max-width: 832px) {
  .toggle-button {
    display: flex;
  }
  .top-row {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .navbar {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
  }
  .top-row ul {
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .top-row li {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .top-row li a {
    padding: .5rem 1rem;
  }
  .top-row.active {
    display: flex;
  }
  .logo {
    margin-top: 9px;
    margin-left: 4px;
  }
}

.expand {
  height: 235px;
}

.shrink {
  height: 54px;
}

.logo {
  padding-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 4px;
  max-width: 200px;
}

.disable-select {
  user-select: none;
}

.html-js-css {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 4rem
}

.about-us {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 3rem
}

.about-us-text {
  max-width: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.logo-colour {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 3rem;
  background-color: #D9BCA9;
}

.history-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 25% 25%;
  grid-template-rows: 50% 50%;
  margin: 4rem;
  margin-bottom: 11rem;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 4rem;
}

.hist-image-1,
.hist-text-1,
.hist-text-2,
.hist-image-2 {
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}

@media (max-width: 60em) {
  .history-grid {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 25%);
    gap: 4rem
  }
}

@media (max-width: 30em) {
  .history-grid {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 10% 40% 40% 10%;
    margin-bottom: 15rem;
    gap: 4rem
  }
}

.share-us-on {
  text-align: center;
}

.share-btn {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 5rem;
  width: 217px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #D9BCA9;
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.share-btn:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1)
}

.share-btn a {
  color: black;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.email-btn {
  position: fixed;
  margin: 10px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  background-color: #D9BCA9;
  border: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: +2;
}

.email-btn a {
  color: black;
  font-size: 21px;
}

.logo-bottom {
  padding-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 4px;
  max-width: 200px;
}

.navbar-bottom {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #D9BCA9;
  height: 60px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.bottom-row ul {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-right: 60px;
  font-size: small;
}

.bottom-row li {
  list-style: none;
}

.bottom-row li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 1rem;
  display: block;
  color: black;
}

@media(max-width: 832px) {
  .bottom-row {
    display: none;
  }
}

.grid-body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh
}

.team-title {
  text-align: center;
}

.profile-pics-1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 4rem;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 4rem;
}

.profile-pics-2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 4rem;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 4rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="disable-select">
  <nav class="navbar">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Hot Beans Logo" title="Logo">
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="toggle-button">
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
    </a>
    <div class="top-row">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Meet The Team</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Vacancies and Qualifications</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Web Dev Courses</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Apply</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
<div class="grid-body">
  <div class="profile-pics-1">
    <div class="grid-item prof-image-1">
      <img src="images/favicon.ico">
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item prof-image-2">
      <img src="images/favicon.ico">
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item prof-image-3">
      <img src="images/favicon.ico">
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item prof-image-4">
      <img src="images/favicon.ico">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="team-title">
    <h1 class="meet-our-team">Meet our Team</h1>
    <p class="team-subheading">Meet the Hot Beans team</p>
  </div>
  <div class="profile-pics-2">
    <div class="grid-item prof-image-5">
      <img src="images/favicon.ico">
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item prof-image-6">
      <img src="images/favicon.ico">
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item prof-image-7">
      <img src="images/favicon.ico">
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item prof-image-8">
      <img src="images/favicon.ico">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="email-btn">
  <a href="#">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-envelope"></i>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="disable-select">
  <nav class="navbar-bottom">
    <div class="logo-bottom">
      <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Hot Beans Logo" title="Logo">
    </div>
    <div class="bottom-row">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Meet The Team</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Vacancies and Qualifications</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Web Dev Courses</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Apply</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> now want to be able to wrap my flexbox so that each image stacks on top of each other

I added `flex-direction: column` to the profile-pics and see what your issue is. I resolved this by changing `.grid-body {height: 100vh}` to `.grid-body {min-height: 100vh}`